# The average radius of an ellipse

Tags: integration, geometry

I have recently been studying the 3rd Kepler´s law which uses the average radius of an orbit. I would love to know how to find the geometric average radius of an ellipse. Would you please show me or at least help me with the process of integration?

Comment: Please refer to another answer of mine [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2593146/why-mathematically-does-a-closed-curve-parametrized-by-theta-give-the-corre/2593173#2593173)

Comment: Beware: in the context of books presenting [Kepler's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion), by "average radius" of an elliptic orbit they mean the semi-major axis, that is the average between maximum and minimum distance of a planet from the Sun. That is not what I would call "average radius" from a mathematical point of view.

Comment: @Aretino But I find it interesting that the average distance weighted by arc length _is_ the same as the semi-major axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

The polar equation of the [ellipse with one focus at the origin and the other at the positive real axis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819468/parametric-equation-of-ellipse-with-foci-at-origin) ($e = $ eccentricity) is:

$$r = \frac{a(1 - e^2)}{1 - e\cos(\theta)}.$$

And the average radius can be calculated using the integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}r(\theta)d\theta.$$

Can you continue?

Update: [already asked at Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/23773/can-one-approximate-the-semi-major-axis-of-an-orbit-as-the-average-orbital-dista). The important fact:

> It's the semi-major axis that defines the period, not the average distance.

Bottom line: the "simple average" $\ne$ the *integral* average. Also interesting (and different): the *time* average.

Update 2: doing the cov $z = \tan(\theta/2)$,
$$\int\frac{1}{1 - e\cos(\theta)}d\theta = \int\frac{1}{1 - e\frac{1 - z^2}{1 + z^2}}\frac{2}{1 + z^2}dz = \int\frac{2}{(1 + e)z^2 + (1 - e)}dz =$$
$$ = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - e^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 + e}}{\sqrt{1 - e}}z\right) =
\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 - e^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1 + e}}{\sqrt{1 - e}}\tan(\theta/2)\right).$$

Comment: The result is $a\sqrt{1 - e^2}$, that is the semi-minor axis, but this is not what is meant by "average radius" in high-school books when presenting Kepler's third law.

Comment: @Aretino, see the update.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla How difficult is that integral to solve without the use of WolframAlpha?

Comment: @AdamPáltik, the "universal change" $z = \tan(x/2)$ (http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter24/section03.html) reduces it to a rational. I can do and post the calculations if you are interested.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I would much appreciate that! :)

Comment: @AdamPáltik, I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: Is there not a sign error in the denominator of your expression for r?

Comment: Nevermind! Your formula is correct for an ellipse with one focus at the origin and the other on the positive real axis, as you clearly stated. I am used to the form with one focus at the origin and the other on the negative real axis.

Answer (score 2):

@Martin-Blas has already suggested two possible notions of average

1. Take an average with respect to $\theta$, the central angle
2. Take an average with respect to time, i.e.,$$
   \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T \| u(t) \| dt,
   $$
   where $T$ is the period, and $u(t)$ is the position of the planet at time $t$, and the sun is located at the origin of the coordinate system.

There's a third notion, which is

3. An average with respect to arclength, i.e., $$
   \int_0^L \| u(t) \| ds$$
   where $L$ is the total arclength of the ellipse, and $ds = \|u'(t)\| dt$ is  arclength integrand.

I'm pretty certain that one could even hoke up some others, but the key thing here is the one mentioned by others: this question doesn't have an answer until you know the measure with respect to which the "average" is being computed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of that average radius means in this context. E.g. if we define average radius of an ellipse as the radius $r$ of a circle which has the same area an an ellipse whose length of the semi-major and semi-minor axis are $a$ and $b$ then
$$
Area = \pi r^2 = \pi ab
$$

which gives $r = \sqrt {ab}$.

Alternative definition is to literally take the average of $a$ and $b$ or $r = \frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: Is it as simple as this?

Comment: No. It is as simple as or as complicated as your definition of average. So in your question you need to clearly define what is the meaning of "average radius" in this context.